# Why is my API request giving error response 404?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm building an app on android studio which requires me to send POST requests and get responses from APIs based on an Odoo framework. 
My LoginActivity sends POST request using a JSONObjectRequest method and returns the required response, which takes us to the MainActivity wherein I need to send another request to another API to get the required response. But when I send this second request, I am getting an error like so :

```
2020-07-14 21:22:57.037 1134-1194/com.example.firstdraft E/Volley: [2792] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://XXX.XXXXXX.XXX/XXX/XXX/
```

Has anyone else faced a similar error or know what needs to be done to solve it?

My LoginActivity code is as follows:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username,password;
    Button login;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    String user, pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button) findViewById((R.id.login));


        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                user = username.getText().toString();
                pass = password.getText().toString();
                postData(requestQueue);
            }
        });
    }
    public void openDashboard() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }
    public void postData(RequestQueue requestQueue){
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            // Creation of JSON Object to be sent 
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String url = getResources().getString(R.string.loginurl);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, object,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        JSONArray key = response.names();
                        String k = null;
                        try {
                            k = key.getString(2);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if () { // condition satisfied
                            /*System.out.println(response);*/
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            openDashboard();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println(error);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String,String> getHeaders() {
                HashMap<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String,String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

My MainActivity code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    private Spinner dropdown;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        postData(requestQueue);
    }

    public void postData(RequestQueue requestQueue) {
        JSONObject object = null;
        try {
            object = jsonCreate();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String url = getResources().getString(R.string.url2);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, object,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            // Whatever needs to be done with the response
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println(error);
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    
    public JSONObject jsonCreate() throws JSONException {
        // Creation of JSON Object
    }
}
```

Comment: `Unexpected response code 404 for http://XXX.XXXXXX.XXX/XXX/XXX/` means that whatever `http://XXX.XXXXXX.XXX/XXX/XXX/` is was not found on the server. So, first things first, you should verify that address is correct.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I tested the address and request object in Postman and it works perfectly there. So i doubt it is the address...

Comment: you can not use request on the main thread, also you can not directly use http protocol

Comment: So how do I do it instead? @Style-7